# How to set GWT properties that validate in HTML5?

Tags: html, gwt

GWT uses this code to set a locale (see [docs](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideI18nLocale#LocaleSpecifying)):

```
<meta name="gwt:property" content="locale=ja_JP">
```

But, unfortunately, this code does not validate as HTML 5.

W3C validator reports this error message:

> Bad value gwt:property for attribute name on element meta: Keyword
>   gwt:property is not registered.

Is there a way to set a property (a locale for example) in the GWT host page in an HTML 5 compliant way?

Answer (score 0):

The locale selection is done in your gwt bootstrap code (APPNAME.nocache.js). So you have only the two options (meta tag / url parameter) mentioned in your referenced docs if you don't want to hack gwts code generator.

But the reported error is not really serious and does no harm. So I would recommend to leave it as it is.